# Can you add custom extensions to WPML?

Tags: wordpress, translation, wpml

I am using WPML to translate a religious website. I have the scripture stored in the database where each verse is a post. In WPML, translation is slow as one must open a verse, which is only one line long, translate it, save it and move on to the next.

I have tried automatic translation but they are not accurate enough and manual translation is too slow. I have also talked to WPML support but they don't have a solution.

Any suggestions welcome. Thank you :)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You want to translate posts of a custom post type ("verse") in some automated manner? Why not, for example, translate them elsewhere and then import as a CSV into WPML with WP All Import? Here's [a guide](https://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/wpml-all-import-plugin-website-import-with-wpml/), read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If the automatic translation is not good enough I think that you have three options:

1. [Use professional translation service](https://wpml.org/documentation/translating-your-contents/professional-translation-via-wpml/)
2. [Automatic translation](https://wpml.org/documentation/automatic-translation/) but with different service, e.g. try DeepL of Google Translate if you were using Bing
3. [Review text that was automatically translated](https://wpml.org/documentation/automatic-translation/how-to-review-automatic-translations-on-your-site/)